# How to pass parameter to a python script when I pipe it to a Django shell

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

So I have an integration test that tests multiple components of my application together, the whole end-to-end test. I need to pipe it to Django shell in order to be able to access models etc. But I also need to pass a parameter to the script. This is what I am doing:

```
venv/bin/python src/manage.py shell < src/integration_tests/endtoend.py
```

But what I want to do is:

```
venv/bin/python src/manage.py shell < src/integration_tests/endtoend.py -o 2
```

If I do that, it throws an exception though:

```
Usage: src/manage.py shell [options] 

Runs a Python interactive interpreter. Tries to use IPython, if it's available.

src/manage.py: error: no such option: -o
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Just curious to why you didn't write it as a standard test?

Comment: @Lennart Regebro Because it's integration test. There should be a clear separation between unit tests, integration tests, BDD tests etc. Unit tests should be completely isolated and only test single units of your application. Also, my integration test is calling a third service API and parsing it's response so it cannot be run together with unit tests. When I run ./manage.py test myapp I don't want to make any connection outside of my box so I can run the tests even on box that is not connected to the internet.

Comment: That they should be separated doesn't mean that they shouldn't be written using unittest. :-) Put them in a separate app and they'll be run separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a Python script that takes parameters and outputs the script so you can pipe it to manage.py.

```
python src/integration_tests/endtoend.py -o 2 | python src/manage.py shell
```

I'm pretty sure I wouldn't do that, but that's what you need to do to pass in command line parameters.

Other options are environment variables and configuration files.